# Android Native C++ Debugging: Stepping causes "no source available"

Tags: android, debugging, android-ndk, gdb

I am attempting to debug a native C++ app on android which uses the cocos2d-x engine. Currently, my C++ breakpoints are hit perfectly after the debugger has settled, but any time I try to step through the code, I immediately get a "no source available" message in the source view.

I am using the "Debug As - Android Native Application" with the ADK bundle and NDK. I have added `NDK_DEBUG=1` to my Build Command and added `android:debuggable="true"` to my manifest xml.

Is there something else I'm missing to make my debug stepping work?

Thanks in advance!

*Update:* I'm also getting the following warnings in my console when I start debugging:

```
warning: sh_link not set for section `.ARM.exidx'
warning: Could not load shared library symbols for 66 libraries, e.g. libstdc++.so.
Use the "info sharedlibrary" command to see the complete listing.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
warning: Breakpoint address adjusted from 0xb00058f5 to 0xb00058f4.
```

I have tried executing `set solib-search-path /cygdrive/c/mygameproject/android/obj/local/armeabi:/cygdrive/c/mygameproject/android/obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug` in a cygwin terminal, but this seems to have no impact on the warnings or issue at hand.

Comment: You need to debug via the ndk_gdb app, not eclipse.  It may be possible to integrate the two, but it isn't easy-  I've seen a dozen sets of instructions over the years and never gotten any to work.  You may be able to wrap that gdb version in ddd to give a graphical app, I haven't tried it.  It's such a pain I just use log debugging for C++ on Android.

Comment: The warning you're getting at launch is very similar to what I get when I debug, I ignore it.

Comment: There have been one or two times where I am able to step return or step over successfully, but soon after I seem to loose my debugging environment when tries to step into a pthread call, even though I never used "step in"...

Comment: I have had the similar problems with debugging but now I have switched to Nvidia's Debug Manager for Android and I can say it's more stable than the one you are using. If your problem persists, you can take a look at it, easy to setup and use.

Answer (score 0):

We haven't seen that exact issue, but we've fixed similar problems in the Apportable fork of gdb available in binary form in the [Apportable SDK](http://www.apportable.com/) and in source on [github](https://github.com/apportable/gdb).

Debugging cocos2d is a common use case for our users and that stepping problem has not come up.

It may take a bit of finagling to work with a pure NDK app, but it shouldn't be too bad.